# openGauss installation issue

Tags: compilation, open-gauss

i am hitting an issue when installing openGauss:

```
File "/xxx/script/gspylib/os/gsfile.py", line 25, in <module>
raise Exception("[GAUSS-52200] : Unable to import module: %s." % str(e))
Exception: [GAUSS-52200] : Unable to import module: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__psutil_linux).
```

I tried both python2 and python3, but didnt work. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `psutil` is a 3rd party dependency. And this library will compile some binary dynamic-link libraries. As you see, the function `PyInit__psutil_linux` is an interface to initialize this library. I believe the incompatible Python version caused the error.
I suggest for you:

1. Try to use a specific Python version to run the startup scripts. For example, the openGauss installation scripts rely on Python 3.6+.
2. Reinstall the psutil by using `pip`:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall psutil
python3 -m pip install psutil  # or psutil==xxx, give a specific version.
```